# Multi line comment in SASS throwing error

Tags: sass

I am using multi-line comments

/*
* common styles go here
*/
style definitions continue...

I get an error in compilation. It says:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "*/": expected identifier, was ""
```

Please note: I am not using SCSS and I do not wish. Don't ask me why. So kindly post answers that do not contain SCSS solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to indent the comment `*/` along with the content by at least 2 spaces, if you are using it on a multiline. Here's an example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjJAbQ

```css
/* This should work */

///*
//This won't work!
//*/

///*
//This will not work
//  */

/**
  * This is a multi line comment
  * And this should work.
  */

// This is a sass comment
.someClass
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  background: #000
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Milan. It worked. I forgot, Ruby parses strictly on the basis of indentation. And that's the only key

Comment: Great! Mark this post as an answer if it has solved exactly what you were looking for.